# C# form.show() does not run in a timer

Tags: c#

I have been trying to run a program that will have to show a form after some time has passed.
I simplified the problem to this:

```
        privet int numbertest;
        privet Timer testtimer = new Timer(10000);

        public void starttimer()
                {
                        testtimer.Elapsed += Testtimer_Elapsed;
                        testtimer.Start();
                }

        private void Testtimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            numbertest++;

            switch (numbertest)
            {
                case 1:
                    MessageBox.Show("1");
                    break;
                case 2:

                    var form = new Form2();
                    form.Show();

                    break;
                case 3:
                    testtimer.Stop();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

when the timer reaches `case 2:` the `form.Show();` does not run as it would outside of a timer.

`.Show()` after a couple of seconds shows a blank glitchy box which has no info inside and you can't close it. In around 10 seconds it will close itself.

I also tried `.Showdialog` which works but it will stop the timer and does not let the user use other parts of the application (as it should).

the problem is not with the `.Show()` as it will run outside the timer method. but if the timer calls any method with `.Show()` inside it, `.Show()` will not run (as it usually does).

if there if any other way to show a win form window without using the `.Show()` I'm happy to try it.

Form2 does not have to have anything inside to have this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Since we know nothing about the Form2 class we can't help you.

Comment: The Elapsed event runs on a theadpool thread, quite unsuitable to do anything with UI.   You must use a synchronous timer, use the one available in the designer toolbox.

Comment: Use `Timer` from `System.Windows.Forms` namespace, not the one from `System.Timers`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` instead of `System.Timers` and it worked. which is a synchronous timer. (as far as I understand) this means the timer and `form.Show()` line can run at the same time.

as Adassko and Hans Passant pointed out in the comments.